# How to include only specific methods in TestNG using a Factory

Tags: java, xml, testng

With TestNG it's possible to include/exclude specific methods in the testng xml file as follows:

```
<classes>
  <class name="WebTest">
    <methods>
      <include name="testMethod1"/>
    </methods>
  </class>
</classes>
```

When using a factory to provide instances of `WebTest` the documentation states that you should only include the factory class in the xml, as follows:

```
<classes>
  <class name="WebTestFactory" />
</classes
```

The problem is that when using a factory, TestNG runs all annotated methods of the class `WebTest`. What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
<classes>
  <class name="WebTestFactory">
    <methods>
      <include name="testMethod1"/>
    </methods>
  </class>
</classes>
```

Where `testMethod1` is a method belonging to the class `WebTest`, and where instances of `WebTest` are returned by the `WebTestFactory`.

However, whenever I try this TestNG complains that `WebTestFactory` does not include `testMethod1`.

Is there a way to specify method inclusion / exclusion in the XML file when using a factory with TestNG?

Answer (score 1):

```
Follow Below Procedure

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="DesignRoom" verbose="1">
    <!-- suite name="Suite Name" -->

        <test name="TestcaseName" allow-return-values="true">

        <!-- packagename.Testcase class name -->
        <classes>
            <class name="packageName.ClassName">
                <methods>
                    <include name="methodName" /> <!-- Enter Method which you want to Run -->
                    <exclude name="methodName" /> <!-- Enter Method which you don't want to Run -->

                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>


    </test>

</suite>
```

Comment: Code only answers are really discouraged. To help future readers, please explain what you are doing too!

Comment: This answer does not address how to mix this with a factory.

Answer (score 0):

As I know it is not possible to filter method from a factory. Include/Exclude are used when you mix a factory and test methods in the same class.
I opened a ticket about the need: https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1253 Feel free to comment there.

As a workaround, you can try to implement [a method interceptor](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#methodinterceptors) which will disable test methods depending on your business logic (for example, system properties).

Comment: Thanks for the response, and for opening the issue! For now a config file of some sort + method interceptor seems like a good option.

Answer (score 0):

My goal was somewhat different but maybe it can help on your problem too. I wanted to run every test method in a new class instance. The main idea is that with a method interceptor you can define which method to run from those that hase no dependencies. Note that you can pass down variables via context from data provider till the interceptor. Maybe you can use that to define which method to run. Here is how I implemented it:

testng.xml

```
 <test name="test">
    <groups>
        <run>
            <include name="g1"/>
        </run>
    </groups>
    <classes>
        <class name="ParallelTest">
            <methods>
            </methods>
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>
```

the class

```
public class ParallelTest {

private final String testToRun;

@DataProvider
public static Object[][] dp(ITestContext context) {
    return new Object[][]{
            new Object[]{"test1", context},
            new Object[]{"test2", context}             
    };
}

@Factory(dataProvider = "dp")
public ParallelTest(String testToRun, ITestContext context) {
    this.testToRun = testToRun;
    context.setAttribute("testToRun", testToRun);
}

@BeforeMethod(groups = "g1")
void beforeMethodG1() {
    System.out.printf("class id: %s, group name: g1, test to run: %s\n", this, testToRun );
}

@BeforeMethod(groups = "g2")
void beforeMethodG2() {
    System.out.println("g2");
}

@Test
    (groups = "g1")
void test1() {
    System.out.printf("class id: %s, group name: g1, test to run: %s, actual test: %s\n", this, testToRun, "test1" );
}

@Test
    (groups = "g1")
void test2() {
    System.out.printf("class id: %s, group name: g1, test to run: %s, actual test: %s\n", this, testToRun, "test2" );
}

@AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
void afterMethod(Method method) {
    System.out.println("after " + method.getName());
}
```

}

the interceptor

```
public class MethodInterceptor implements IMethodInterceptor {
@Override
public List<IMethodInstance> intercept(List<IMethodInstance> methods, ITestContext context) {
    List<String> methodNamesToRun = new ArrayList<>(methods.size());
    List<Object> classInstancesToRun = new ArrayList<>(methods.size());
    List<IMethodInstance> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (IMethodInstance methodInstance : methods) {
        Object classInstance = methodInstance.getMethod().getInstance();
        String methodName = methodInstance.getMethod().getQualifiedName();
        if (!classInstancesToRun.contains(classInstance) && !methodNamesToRun.contains(methodName)) {
            result.add(methodInstance);
            classInstancesToRun.add(classInstance);
            methodNamesToRun.add(methodName);
        }
    }
    context.getAttribute("testToRun");
    return result;
}
```

}

result

```
class id: ParallelTest@20d3d15a, group name: g1, test to run: test1
class id: ParallelTest@20d3d15a, group name: g1, test to run: test1, actual test: test1
after test1
class id: ParallelTest@2893de87, group name: g1, test to run: test2
class id: ParallelTest@2893de87, group name: g1, test to run: test2, actual test: test2
after test2
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the `@Factory` notation on a constructor of the test class with a `dataProvider` attribute, like this

```
public class TestFoo
{
  static final String TEST_NAMES = "testNames";

  @Nonnull
  private final String testName;

  @Factory(dataProvider = TEST_NAMES)
  public TestFoo(@Nonnull String testName)
  {
    this.testName = testName;
  }

  @DataProvider(name = TEST_NAMES)
  public static Object[][] testNames()
  {
    Object[][] names = new Object[][]{{"Foo"}, {"Bar"}, {"Baz"}};
    return names;
  }

  @Test
  public void nameTest()
  {
    System.out.println("Name = " + testName);
    Assert.assertFalse(testName.isBlank());
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Name = Bar
Name = Foo
Name = Baz

===============================================
Default Suite
Total tests run: 3, Passes: 3, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


Process finished with exit code 0
```